# Getting __construct() must be an instance of App\Models\Page, none given message

Tags: php, laravel-5

When trying to access a function in another controller, I am getting a `__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\Page, none given` error message and I am wondering how to solve this...

The controller where the function is called from:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\PagesController;
...
class ModulesController extends Controller {

    public function filter(Request $request) {
        $items = $this->loadFilteredItems($request->module_id, $request->filters);
        $page = new PagesController();
        $header = $page->loadElements($request->id, false);
        return View::make(
            'base.frontend.' . config('folder') . '.includes.filter', 
            compact('items', 'header'));
        }
    }
}
```

The controller that stores the function:

```
class PagesController extends Controller {

    private $page;

    public function __construct(Page $page) {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

    private function loadElements($id) {
        return 'something';
    }

}
```

Comment: Error message states exactly what the problem is. You need to pass an instance of `App\Models\Page` .  `$page = new PagesController();` change to `$page = new PagesController($instanceOfModelPage);`

Comment: But how do I make the instance?

Comment: Did not work with laravel. Easiest way `$instanceOfModelPage = new App\Models\Page();`  Based on docs looks like original dev overwrote default constructor as by default `Controller::__construct` accepts nothing. Take a look how it is getting called in other place. Just search for `PagesController` through codebase

Comment: Bummer, wasn't working. So I just deleted the whole construct method and made a new static function that calls the private function within the PagesController. Thanx for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Adapted the Controllers into this:

```
class ModulesController extends Controller {

    public function filter(Request $request) {
        $items = $this->loadFilteredItems($request->module_id, $request->filters);
        $page = new PagesController();
        $header = $page->loadHeaderElements($request->id);
        return View::make(
            'base.frontend.' . config('folder') . '.includes.filter', 
            compact('items', 'header'));
        }
    }
}

class PagesController extends Controller {

    /**
    Removed these lines
    private $page;

    public function __construct(Page $page) {
        $this->page = $page;
    }
    **/

    public static function loadHeaderElements($id) {
        return $this->loadElements($id);
    }

    private function loadElements($id) {
        return 'something';
    }

}
```

And it's working now